# Passing data from ViewController to UITableView in another VIewController

Tags: swift, xcode, protocols

I would like to pass data from `DetailedCellVC` View Controller to UITableView on a different ViewController using a protocol.

First, I've created a protocol:

```
protocol DetailedCellDelegate {
    func getDetailedCellInfo(title: String)
}
```

Then, I've created a delegate variable inside `DetailedCellVC`:

```
var cellDelegate: DetailedCellDelegate?
```

in `DetailedCellVC` I have created a label:

```
let titleLabel: UILabel = {
    let lbl = UILabel()
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0
    lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    lbl.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 26)
    lbl.textAlignment = .center
    return lbl
}()
```

After that, I used this `titleLabel` in my protocol func:

```
@objc func didTapAddBarButton() {
        
        guard let title = titleLabel.text else { return }
        
        cellDelegate?.getDetailedCellInfo(title: title)
    }
```

Then, in another ViewController `FavouriteNewsVC` I've added a line `detailedCellVC.cellDelegate = self`

To make it work, I've created an extension with my protocol:

```
extension FavouriteNewsVC: DetailedCellDelegate {
func getDetailedCellInfo(title: String) {
    titleLabel.text = title
}
}
```

and with TableView protocol:

```
extension FavouriteNewsVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return favouriteNews.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomCell
        
        if let title = favouriteNews[indexPath.row].title {
            cell.titleLabel.text = title
        }
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I click on "Add Bar Button" in `DetailedCellVC` it doesn't add the `titleLabel` to my tableView in `FavouriteNewsVC`. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: if you are navigating from one to another you can use segue it much better in this case

Comment: Maybe you should try func getDetailedCellInfo(title: String) {
    titleLabel.text = title tableView.reloadData()
}

Comment: @mehmett it doesn't work :/